# TimeZone - how to distinguish between GMT time zone and unrecognized time zone?

Tags: java, datetime

When you create an instance of `java.util.TimeZone` class based on a Custom ID which is unrecognized (e.g. has a typo) you get a GMT time zone.

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europ/Zurich"); //'e' missing in 'Europe'
System.out.println(timezone.getID()); //result: "GMT"
```

How should I distinguish between a "real" GMT time zone and an unrecognized one?

Comment: Compare the ID to the original one?

Comment: There is nothing to compare. I get the Custom ID from an external source. I want to be sure if this was a correct, valid Custom ID

Comment: Compare that custom ID to the result of `getID()` from the newly created time zone, instead of just printing it. If they are not the same, it means the custom ID was not itself "GMT" so it must have been invalid. Anyway, you can always check the ID vs the list of valid IDs *before* creating the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find a direct API to do this. You can use get ID's and then look for a match . Just a reference impl. here

```
Set<String> timezones = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()));

System.out.println(timezones.contains("Europ/Zurich"));
System.out.println(timezones.contains("Europe/Zurich"));
```

Comment: Custom ID can have a different format (e.g. GMT+01:00), not listed in the available IDs